# JSON Format from List

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a RESTFul service that returns a list in JSON format. The JSON Format looks like this:

```
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "6F5HH",
"location": "15 Azua - IP",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "7/14/2017 9:58:31 AM",
"cant": 14,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "356612023737986"
},
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "6F5HH",
"location": "15 Azua - IP",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "7/20/2017 11:46:10 AM",
"cant": 1,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "356612023737986"
},
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "5UG71",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:35:29 PM",
"cant": 16,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
},
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "9LKYH",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "52%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:38:09 PM",
"cant": 13,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
},
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "A3MA1",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "32%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:38:09 PM",
"cant": 22,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
}
```

As you can see, this was a 5 items List. What I need to do is generate the JSON without separating each item with a comma. So the output have to be something like this:

```
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "6F5HH",
"location": "15 Azua - IP",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "7/14/2017 9:58:31 AM",
"cant": 14,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "356612023737986"
}
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "6F5HH",
"location": "15 Azua - IP",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "7/20/2017 11:46:10 AM",
"cant": 1,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "356612023737986"
}
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "5UG71",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "36%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:35:29 PM",
"cant": 16,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
}
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "9LKYH",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "52%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:38:09 PM",
"cant": 13,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
}
{
"cantidad": 241,
"reply": "A3MA1",
"location": "AES NO REGISTRADO",
"str": "32%",
"date_Sent": "8/1/2017 1:38:09 PM",
"cant": 22,
"vehiculo": "",
"lc": "357042063498597"
}
```

This is my Register Method of a .NET WebApi App:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); //DEVOLVER SOLO JSON 
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting       = Formatting.Indented;                          
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that invalid json?

Comment: @GuaGua0308: the original JSON is actually correct. What you want to transform it into, is incorrect. Have you even tried to load your desired JSON into a JSON editor? It's badly formed!!!

Comment: @L.B Why ist that invalid JSON? It is [known](http://jsonlines.org/) and [supported](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) - The first sample here is invalid because of the missing square brackets

Comment: @SirRufo https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @L.B So you want to say JSON.Net should drop supporting the things described by http://jsonlines.org and someone should tell them (and all other REST API producer returning that kind of data) they are wrong at all?

Comment: @SirRufo No, What I say is : **An invalid json has always been invalid.**. Only you think it is valid.

Comment: @L.B According to Json.Net and jsonlines.org it is not just me

Comment: @SirRufo You are talking too much without testing it (SO doesn't allow me to say what I think). Open you VS, write `var jobj = JObject.Parse(jsonOPwants);` and run it. Then we can talk further. (**I did it before I wrote my comments** ).

Comment: @L.B Ok, check that [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MiETYR) - BTW I checked the documentation before my comments :o)

Comment: @SirRufo `reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;` means you have many jsons in a single file. that doesn't make that file a single valid  json. It is mostly used by streaming APIs like twitter and this is not the case here

Comment: @L.B But you do agree this kind *is supported* by Json.Net?

Comment: @SirRufo Try JavaScriptSerializer or some others. It is just a *plus* from Json.Net and everyone who would consume this json doesn't have to use that library (think consumers using javascript or java )

Comment: @L.B Why should I? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Comment: @L.B I acknowledge that it isn't a clean format. It's just for migrating from SQL SERVER 2008 to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you need to break your JSON, but still. I would use this serializer (you need reference to System.Web.Extensions):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
string jsonStr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
string notJsonStr = jsonStr.Replace("},{", "}{");
return notJsonStr;
```

Do not forget to config your expected content type as "text\plain" instead of "application\json", cause this result string won't be a JSON any more.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I create a HttpResponseMessage method and return de Json with the replace.